# Is it possible to get a property value within the getter for that property?

Tags: c#

I have a basic test console app going with the following property:

```
public static string testString { get{ } set{ } }
```

I want to do a sort of singleton like setup with the property where if the property value is null, I initialize the property and return the property value.  If it's not null, I return the current property value.

Bad practices aside, is this possible without using an additional variable?

Trying to check the value of the property within get{} using traditional means of course creates a stackoverflow exception. I presume each time it tries to check null it's just using the getter again and getting stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: use a private variable inside your class to store the initialized value, check that for null and initialize/return

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I appreciate the correction.  I am very new and will learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) are just syntax sugar for getter/setter methods. So there is no in-build storage behind them.

> Properties can be used as if they are public data members, but they are actually special methods called accessors. This enables data to be accessed easily and still helps promote the safety and flexibility of methods.

Therefore you have to create a field or so.

(There are also [auto-implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), for which which the compiler creates backer fields automatically. But you do not have direct access to these fields anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is quite possible:

```
private static string _testString;

public static string testString { 
   get
   { 
     return _testString = _testString ?? "MyDefaultValue";
   } 
   set
   { 
     _testString = value;
   } 
}
```

Adding a private field will do what you're wanting.  While this may look like an additional variable, this is what actually occurs when your application gets compiled.  No loss of optimization or performance.

Comment: I understood that PO wants to do it "_without using an additional variable_" (meaning "_field_", perhaps).

Comment: @ AlexD -- that is correct.  Sorry if my semantics aren't up to snuff.  :)